# Как задать оптимальное значение QScrollBar::setMaximum(int)

Tags: c++, qt, qscrollbar

Нужно отобразить в окне информацию из большого кол-ва текстовых файлов, к примеру на 300 Гб.

Я сделал QTableView + QAbstractTableModel, но есть проблема. Кол-во строк и длина каждой из строк в каждом файле неизвестны.
Хотел передавать в скроллер значение суммарного объёма в байтах и после, в переопределённом вращении колеса, сдвигать текущее положение скроллера на значение, равное весу строки в байтах, но такие большие значения в int не влезут, да и в документации пишут, что скроллер использует для шагов значения в пределах 100000 всего.

Есть ли способы, как динамически вычислять необходимое максимальное кол-во шагов для скроллера, имея только суммарный размер всех файлов на отображение? К примеру, чтобы данным способом вычислялось необходимое максимальное число шагов как для 600 байт текста на отображение, так и для 600 млрд байт.

Comment: Пересчитайте суммарный объем в шаги. Поделив объем на максимальное количество шагов, получите цену одного шага. Ну и дальше текущее положение пересчитать в количество шагов, и выставить скролл соответственно

Comment: > Есть ли способы, как динамически вычислять необходимое максимальное кол-во шагов для скроллера По моему скроллер QTableView сам из модели данных получает свои параметры max и min значения. > Нужно отобразить в окне информацию из большого кол-ва текстовых файлов, к примеру на 300 Гб. А точно для этого нужен QTableView? Что за информация в файлах (структурированная? с разделителями?) > Я сделал QTableView + QAbstractTableModel QAbstractTableModel? то есть вы сами реализуете модель данных? (data,flags) ?